# Installing OpenCV for Python on 16.04 Xenial Xerus

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, ubuntu-16.04

I've updated Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and now i want to install OpenCV3.1 for Python completely from scratch.
What possibilities are there, or more specific, what's the easiest way without much configuration?

Comment: you mean, you want to compile it yourself ? If you use anaconda python, try

Comment: no exactly not. i want a simple and fast way so i can start as quick as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [anaconda python](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and install it.

In a console:

[search for compiled opencv packages](https://conda.anaconda.org/):

`anaconda search -t conda opencv`

select a channel and install e.g:

`conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/bobpkgs opencv3`

And look and the [conda documentation](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/intro.html).

Comment: maybe you have to do install the anaconda client by `conda install anaconda` after installing as described in the HOWTO from the website.

Comment: Thanks for that guide. I will try and response later.

Comment: This short guide worked perfect for me. Anaconda is a very usefull tool, too.

Comment: you might also want to look into skimage. Bit easier than opencv but not that well documented yet